# How to install downloaded version of Doctrine 2.2 ORM

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, autoload

I have downloaded the latest version of Doctrine ORM and on their site it says: 
"See the configuration section on how to configure and bootstrap a downloaded version of Doctrine."

Then i go there ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html ) and i find at "class loading" section, that i have to add the following line to my project:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
```

Where's that autoload.php file? Where's the vendor folder? I don't get it...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded the 'latest version' it included that autoload file. Locate it in the download and change the file path in the require_once function the the path of the file:

```
require_once "/location/of/files/you/downloaded/vendor/autoload.php";
```

As you can see about 400px down on the page here, you need to use to PEAR to install the files first:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

Comment: At the downloaded version there is no autoload file. There's just 2 folders (bin, doctrine) and none of them includes any autoload.php file. There's just an "Autoload.php" file inside Doctrine/ORM/Proxy/Autoloader.php

Do i need to use PEAR to have that file?? I though there were 2 ways to install it. By pear or by downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by installing composer first. Follow the guide in this page http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md. There's a description for Windows and Unix users, this will install composer, then create a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
      "doctrine/orm": "2.*",
      "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
  }
}
```

Then from the cmd/terminal, run this command: `composer install`

You will find that the `vendor` folder is created automatically.